# How do I address the Recipient of this Non disclosure agreement?

Tags: non-disclosure, confidentiality

When a non disclosure agreement (NDA) is between an individual (the Discloser) and a Director of a research institute (the Recipient), how should the Recipient be addressed? Just as an individual or as a director? Or should I address only the research institute? (see example below)

**Option 1:** 
Parties:
[name and surname of the director] of [address where the director lives]
(the Recipient)
and

[name of the individual disclosing the information] of [address of individual]

(the Discloser)

**Option 2:** 
Parties:
[name and surname of the director] of [address where the director lives, do I need their personal address?], director of [name of the research institute], [address of the research institute]
(the Recipient)
and

[name of the individual disclosing the information] of [address of individual]

(the Discloser)

Comment: What secrets does the director (rather than the institute) not want disclosed?

Comment: @DaleM thats a rather ... interesting question given the topic :D

Comment: @Moo I mean, why am I signing it with a person I don't work for (the director) rather than the organisation that I do work for?

Comment: It's between an individual inventor disclosing the idea to a director of a research institute to see if they are interested in collaborating in a proof of concept. The meeting is only between the inventor and the director who will help in finding the potential people to involve and with individuating fundings sources .